# H-space multiplication for a CW-complex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Let $(X,\mu,e)$ be an $H$-space (so $\mu:X\times X\to X$ is a continuous map and $e\in X$ is a base point such that $\mu(\cdot,e)\simeq id_X\simeq\mu(e,\cdot)$) and a CW-complex such that $e$ is a $0$-cell for the CW-structure on $X$. I am trying to show that there exists a continuous map $\tilde\mu:X\times X\to X$ such that $\tilde\mu(x,e)=x=\tilde\mu(e,x)$. Supposedly it makes sense to use the homotopy extension property for this, but I fail to see how: I would think that starting at a and building up $X$ from there, you can use the HEP to build the map $\tilde\mu$. Besides the fact that I don't see why that map would satisfy the condition that $\tilde\mu$ should satisfy, and you only have one 0-cell, so how can you get the whole CW-complex starting from this?

Any help/hints are appreciated.

Edit: the answer below seems to be complete, but I can't quite digest it because I don't know what this folding map is.

Edit2: Apparently, the answer below seems to consider $X\bigvee X$ as the subspace $X\times\{e\}\sqcup\{e\}\times X$ of $X^2$, so that the folding map is just $(x,e)\mapsto x$, $(e,x)
\mapsto x$. I don't see how this answer uses the fact that $e$ is a 0-cell.

Comment: The important issue is the point e having a nice neighborhood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that $\mu$ extends the folding map $\nabla:X\vee X\rightarrow X$ over the inclusion $j:X\vee X\hookrightarrow X\times X$, which is a closed cofibration since CW complexes are well-based. We have been given homotopies $F^l_t:\mu(-,e)\simeq id_X$ and $F^r_t:\mu(e,-)\simeq id_X$, and these assemble to give a homotopy $F:\mu\circ j\simeq \nabla:X\vee X\rightarrow X$.

Now apply the HEP for $j$ to the homotopy $F$ and we get a homotopy $G:X\times X\times I\rightarrow X$ starting at $\mu$ and ending at some map $\tilde\mu:X\times X\rightarrow X$ which satisfies $\tilde\mu\circ j=\nabla$ strictly. That is, $\tilde\mu(x,e)=x=\tilde\mu(e,x)$ for each $x\in X$.

Comment: How is the folding map defined?

Comment: The wedge product $X\vee Y$ of two based spaces $X,Y$ is the categorical coproduct in the category of based spaces (although you can think of it as the subset $X\times *\cup *\times Y\subseteq X\times Y$). This means that a map $f:X\vee Y\rightarrow Z$ is completely determined by a pair of maps $f_X:X\rightarrow Z$ and $f_Y:Y\rightarrow Z$. We often write $f=(f_X,f_Y)$. When $X=Y=Z$ the fold map is defined by $\nabla=(id_X,id_X)$. Explicitly $\nabla(x,*)=x=\nabla(*,x)$.

Comment: I see. But why does $(X\times X,X\bigvee X)$ have the HEP?

Comment: Since CW complexes are paracompact Hausdorff the inclusion of a 0-cell basepoint is a closed cofibration $e\hookrightarrow X$. As is the identity $X\xrightarrow{=}X$. The product of cofibrations is again a cofibration, as is the union of cofibrations. Hence $X\vee X=X\times \ast\cup\ast\times X\hookrightarrow X\times X$ is a closed cofibration.

Comment: The issue is the  closed cofibration ↪
CW is sufficient but not necessary